# How To Add Attribute to Magento 2.1.x Product Page

Tags: customization, product, custom-attributes, magento2.1

I hope this is a really simple question created only by my newb status to PhP and Magento.

Question: Given the details described below, in the catalog_product_view.xml first attribute.  What should this be to ensure I get my custom attribute gsc_payment?  I can everything to work using a built in attribute like UPC, but not my custom attribute.

1. I created a new attribute and made it visible on Magento's Products Page. 
   Attribute Code: gsc_payment
   Default Label: ARC 90 Payment
2. I opened catalog_product_view.xml from
   /home/XXXXXXXX/public_html/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/gosmart/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml and added the referenceContainer shown below.

   ```
   <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">
       <block  class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" 
           name="product.info.gsc" 
           template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/gsc.phtml" 
           after="product.info.upc">
           <arguments>
               <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getGSC_Payment</argument>
               <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">gsc_payment</argument>
               <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">gsc_payment</argument>
               <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">Arc 90 Payment:</argument>
               <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="gsc_payment"</argument>
           </arguments>
       </block>
   </referenceContainer>




   <referenceContainer name="product.info.main">


       <block class="Ves\Themesettings\Block\Product\View" name="ves.product.info.main" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/product_info_main.phtml">
           <move element="product.info.sku" as="product_info_sku" destination="ves.product.info.main"/>

           <move element="product.info.review" as="product_info_review" destination="ves.product.info.main"/>
           <move element="product.price.final" as="product_price_final" destination="ves.product.info.main"/>
           <move element="product.price.tier" as="product_price_tier" destination="ves.product.info.main"/>
           <move element="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" destination="ves.product.info.main"/>
           <move element="product.info" as="product_info" destination="ves.product.info.main"/>
           <move element="product.info.overview" as="product_info_overview" destination="ves.product.info.main"/>
           <move element="require-cookie" as="require_cookie" destination="ves.product.info.main"/>
           <move element="product.info.extrahint" as="product_info_extrahint" destination="ves.product.info.main"/>
           <move element="product.info.type" as="product_info_type" destination="ves.product.info.main"/>
       </block>



   </referenceContainer>
   <container name="product.info.extrahint" as="extrahint" label="Product View Extra Hint">
       <container name="product.info.social" label="Product social links container" after="product.info.overview">
           <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.categories" template="product/view/categories.phtml"/>
       </container>
   ```
3. I created a new file here /home/XXXXXXXXX/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gsc.phtml with the following block code copied from internet.

   ```
   <?php
      $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
      $_product = $block->getProduct();
      $_code = $block->getAtCode();
      $_className = $block->getCssClass();
      $_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
      $_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
      $_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

     if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
         $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontendLabel();
       }

      $_attributeValue =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
       ?>

       <?php if ($_attributeValue): ?>

         <div class="product attibute <?php echo $_className?>">
         <?php if ($_attributeLabel != 'none'): ?><strong class="type"><?php echo $_attributeLabel?></strong><?php endif; ?>
         <div class="value" <?php echo $_attributeAddAttribute;?>><?php echo $_attributeValue; ?></div>

         </div>

   <?php endif; ?>
   ```
4. I then opened /home/XXXXXXXXXXX/public_html/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/gosmart/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/product_info_main.phtml and added the following code inside the existing .

   ```
   <div>
   <table style="width: 100%; border-color: #ac1a2f; border-style: solid; border-width: 2px;">
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <p style="color: red; font-size: 300%; text-align: center;">Buy Today!</p>
                   <div style="color: green; font-size: 400%; text-align: center;">$
                       <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_info_gsc_payment') ?>
                       <?php echo "Hello"?>
                       <?php $_product = $block->getProduct();
                           echo $_product->getPrice();
                           echo $_product->getAttributeText('color');
                       ?>
                   </div>
                   <p style="font-size: 150%; text-align: center;">bi-weekly/12 months</p>
                   <p style="color: red; font-size: 150%; text-align: center;">90 Days Same As Cash</p>
                   <p style="text-align: center;">20-25% Down Payment Required</p>
                   <p style="text-align: center;">Estimated Payment</p>
               </td>
               <td>
                   <div style="text-align: center;">
                       <p><img style="width: 25%; height: 25%;" src="https://1792armory.com/public/firearms/arc90_logo_big.png" border="0" /></p>
                       <p><a href="https://mail.globalcheck.com/cgi-bin/sendprequal.cgi?custid=149209368937458751" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"> <img style="align: center;" src="https://mail.globalcheck.com/images/qualify1.jpg" border="0" /> </a></p>
                   </div>
               </td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom attribute using Setup/upgradeData.php

```
  <?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace Custom\Product\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface {

    public function __construct(\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);



        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.1.24') < 0) {
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'product_height', [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Product Height in cm',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'class' => '',
                'backend' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'visible' => true,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'filterable_in_search' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'unique' => false,
                'group' => 'General',
                'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                'is_filterable_in_grid' => true,
                    ]
            );



        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }

}

?>
```